# Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-wheel, requirements.txt

I got an error when install dependencies for my project!

OS : WinDow 11

Python: 3.10.4 (64bit)

Pip: 22.1.2

```
  Building wheel for django-admin-sortable2 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for django-admin-sortable2: filename=django_admin_sortable2-0.7.5-py3-none-any.whl size=69989 sha256=0a4ff29d0c9b0422611dde61c6c1665dd36b10f98413f4ed7b8532e29afdc03d
  Stored in directory: c:\users\kev\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\99\3e\95\384eeaa2d641ef0c9e8b46e701737b53ae6a973358887816e0
  Building wheel for easy-thumbnails (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for easy-thumbnails: filename=easy_thumbnails-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=69700 sha256=ce66afcd2ca403acf9225b53eed60300c8d37c3bad53dcdf37ebc3a25550bdc6
  Stored in directory: c:\users\kev\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\cb\33\00\f7fa4b381ae4cbaf99674fb7a4411339d38e616cfcc41632c5
  Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [288 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\gevent
      copying src\gevent\ares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\gevent
      copying src\gevent\backdoor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\gevent
      copying src\gevent\baseserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\gevent
      copying src\gevent\builtins.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\gevent
```

Comment: Please provide more info. Which version of gevent you are trying to install, and past more logs.

Comment: @psarka https://pastebin.com/skxSihAz , thank you

Comment: I still don't see the versions, can you also paste your requirements.txt?

Comment: I just edited, pls check again https://pastebin.com/skxSihAz, my requirements.txt : https://pastebin.com/u2BGH5yG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: use python3.8 or update requirement.txt versions.

**More info**:

The combination of (A) gevent==20.9, (B) windows 10, and (C) python3.10 does not have a prebuilt wheel. You can check this kind of stuff by going to pypi and looking what is offered for downloads (https://pypi.org/project/gevent/20.9.0/#files)

I'm assuming that you will not be able to compile things from source yourself (it's a hassle), so you need to change (A), (B) or (C).

(A). Changing this means relaxing or updating the version requirements. For example gevent==21.12 does have a wheel for windows and python3.10

(B). Changing this means not using windows, probably not an option

(C). Changing this means using older python version. For example, python3.8 has a wheel for gevent==20.9.

Comment: Hi, I try to install python 3.8.10  --> run `virtualenv -p python3.8.10` --> insall pyenv-win and run `pyenv global 3.8.10`, gevent fixed but appear another error https://pastebin.com/9KT7yKJU

Comment: You are out of luck :( https://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/issues/247. The recommendation is not to use windows: "My suggestion is to either use the Linux layer of Windows, or just change to a more typical development platform. In fact, basically any other platform would work: BSD, Linux, macOS."

Comment: thank you! I will install Unbuntu now and say goodbye Window :D

Answer (score 3):

`gevent==20.9.0` probably doesn't support Python 3.10, you can downgrade to Python 3.8 or you can try to download and install the latest version of gevent - `gevent 21.12.0` - see https://pypi.org/project/gevent/#downloads.

1. Go to `requirements.txt` and replace the line `gevent==20.9.0` with `gevent==21.12.0`.
2. After that you can try to install all dependencies: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

---

If the solution above doesn't help, try to manually install a `gevent` wheel:

1. Download `greenlet` wheel `greenlet‑1.1.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl` from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#greenlet](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#greenlet)
2. Go to the local directory which contains downloaded `greenlet` wheel and install it

```
pip install greenlet‑1.1.2‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
```

3. Download `gevent` wheel `gevent‑21.12.0‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl` from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gevent](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gevent)
4. Go to the local directory which contains downloaded `gevent` wheel and install it

```
pip install gevent‑21.12.0‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl
```

5. Finally you can remove `gevent==20.9.0` from `requirements.txt` and install other dependencies: `pip install -r requirements.txt`